# Flows in Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\varphi: [0,T] \rightarrow H$ be a Hilbert space valued $C^1$-function. Let $H = X \oplus X^{\perp}$ such that $\varphi(0) \in X$ and the implication $\varphi(t) \in X \Rightarrow \varphi'(t) \in X$ holds.

I ask: How can I show that $\varphi$ stays in $X$? It sounds natural and I guess it is true, but I fail to see how it can be shown.

Comment: On the positive side: assume there is a smooth foliation on $H$ such that $\phi(t)$ is tangent to the leaves. Then  $\phi(t)$ belongs to the same leaf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $\phi(t) = (1-e^{-1/t^2}, t)\in \mathbb R^2$. It satisfies your assumptions for $X= 0\times \mathbb R$, but it does not stay in $X$.

Comment: Or even $\phi(t) = (t^2, t)$.

Comment: In fact even $\phi(t):=t^2$ in $H:=\mathbb{R}$ with $X:=(0)$.